# Dynamically changing a datepicker depending the value selected on a dropdown

Tags: javascript, select, datepicker

Am working on an application whereby am capturing 2 input fields on a form mainly a **select dropdown list** and a **datepicker input field** . The 2 fields are inter-related whereby am **checking the value the user selected in the dropdown list** before **conditionally displaying the number of years** on the datepicker.

For instance if the user selected a user from the dropdown of value **Husband or Wife**. I show, the datepicker with a minimum of 18 years and a maximum of 75 years. This is working fine.

If the user selected Son or Daughter, I want to show a maximum of 18 years in the datepicker. For instance we are in 2019, it should show year range between 16th April 2001 and 16th April 2019. This is not working as expected.

**Markup code**

```
<!-- Gender -->
    <div class="row">
        <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
        <select class="fmRelation" id="relation1" required>
            <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
            <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
            <option value="Son"> Son </option>
            <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
        </select>
    </div>
<!-- END -->

<!-- Date of Birth-->
    <div class="row">
        <label class="fm-inputph3"> Date Of Birth :</label>
        <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
    </div>
<!-- END dob -->
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
//Check Date depending on relation
$(function(){
    var relation1 = $("#relation1").val(); 

    //User selected husband or wife from the dropdown
    if(relation1 == "Husband" || relation1 =="Wife"){
        var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
        maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
        maxBirthdayDate.setMonth(11,31);
        $( function() {
            $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                //yy-mm-dd
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                //Maximum years to show (75 years) from current year
                minDate: maxBirthdayDate + '-75Y',
                maxDate: '-18Y',
                yearRange: '1900:'+maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear()
            });
        });
    }
    //Otherwise son and Daughter was selected
    else{
        var today = new Date();
        today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() -18);
        today.setMonth();

        var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
        maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
        maxBirthdayDate.setMonth(11,31);

        $( function() {
            $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                minDate: today,
                maxDate: '-18Y'   
            });
        });
        //End dob
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working for you as the `function` is running when the page gets loaded and the initial value is `Husband`. So, whatever the user will be selected it doesn't make a difference. So first of all trigger this function on `change` event so whenever the user changes the dropdown, the date picker will change the result accordingly.

Secondly, add `yearRange` for defining the years from 2001 - 2019. Also, change values for the `minDate()` and `maxDate()` to restrict user for selecting any other date which doesn't comes in the range.

```js
//Check Date depending on relation
$(function(){
    $("#relation1").on("change", function() {        
        var relation1 = $("#relation1").val(); 
        //User selected husband or wife from the dropdown
        if(relation1 == "Husband" || relation1 =="Wife"){
            var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
            maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
            maxBirthdayDate.setMonth(11,31);
            $( function() {
                $("#dob").datepicker("destroy");
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    //yy-mm-dd
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    //Maximum years to show (75 years) from current year
                    minDate: maxBirthdayDate + '-75Y',
                    maxDate: '-18Y',
                    yearRange: '1900:'+maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear()
                });
            });
        }
        //Otherwise son and Daughter was selected
        else{
            var today = new Date();
            var minYear = today.getFullYear() - 18;
            var minMonth = today.getMonth();
            var minDate = today.getDate();

            var maxYear = today.getFullYear();
            var maxMonth = today.getMonth();
            var maxDate = today.getDate();

            $( function() {
                console.log(minDate, today)
                $("#dob").datepicker("destroy");
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    minDate: new Date(minYear, minMonth, minDate),
                    maxDate: new Date(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDate),
                    yearRange: minYear + ':' + today.getFullYear() + ''
                });
            });
            //End dob
        }
    });
    $("#relation1").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Gender -->
<div class="row">
    <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fmRelation" id="relation1" required>
        <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
        <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
        <option value="Son"> Son </option>
        <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- END -->

<!-- Date of Birth-->
<div class="row">
    <label class="fm-inputph3"> Date Of Birth :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
</div>
<!-- END dob -->
```

Comment: ,, According to your code snippet,, I changed the dropdown to a value of Son and the years dont change,,  I need to change the years to be less than 18 years in the datepicker

Comment: @Martin I have updated the code and it should work for you now.

Comment: @Martin I have added `yearRange` and removed the `minDate` and `maxDate` to make the things work for you.

Comment: Ahmed   ,,, What about disabling months  and dates,, I need it to be strictly 18 years for (son or daughter) so dates outside 16/04/2001  to 16/04/2019 should be disabled.. the same logic for husband and wife..

Comment: @Martin check now.

Answer (score 0):

In the `else {` the today var was a bit messed up, aditionally i put the whole thing into a function like:

```
<script>
//Check Date depending on relation
function updateDatePicker(){
    $(function(){
        var relation1 = $("#relation1").val(); 

        //User selected husband or wife from the dropdown
        if(relation1 == "Husband" || relation1 =="Wife"){
            var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
            maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
            maxBirthdayDate.setMonth(11,31);
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker("destroy"); // Destroy the DatePicker to then change its values
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    //yy-mm-dd
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    //Maximum years to show (75 years) from current year
                    minDate: maxBirthdayDate + '-75Y',
                    maxDate: '-18Y',
                    yearRange: '1900:'+maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear()
                });
        }
        //Otherwise son and Daughter was selected
        else{
            var today = new Date();
            var maxBirthdayDate = new Date();
            maxBirthdayDate.setFullYear( maxBirthdayDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
            maxBirthdayDate.setMonth(11,31);

                $("#dob").datepicker("destroy"); // Destroy the DatePicker to then change its values
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    minDate: '-18Y',
                    maxDate: today
                });
            //End dob
        }
    });
}
updateDatePicker()
</script>
```

Then in the selector, I added an `onchange event`, due to otherwise the function only running when the page loads and so not updating the DatePicker if you change the dropdown:

```
<div class="row" onchange="updateDatePicker()">
    <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
    <select class="fmRelation" id="relation1" required>
        <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
        <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
        <option value="Son"> Son </option>
        <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And it seems to be working:
[image: PoW]
[image]

Comment: I used your code but it doesnt wrk on my side,, I need to display years between 2001 and 2019 (if the user selected son or daughter )  and between 2001 and 1944 (if  the user selected husband or wife).. This means the children should be under 18 years while parents should be over 18 years and less than 75 years

Comment: How does it not seem to be working for you, what is the issue?

Comment: ,, i need to display the years conditionally depending on the value the user selected in the dropdown..  For instance  if the user selected son or daughter, on the datepicker it should display years between 16th April 2001 and 16th April 2019 (this means the son or daughter is below 18 years),, if the user selected Husband or wife the datepicjker should display between 16th April 1944 and 16th April 2001 which means the husband/wife is between 18 years and 75 years..

Comment: I found some issue where `after selecting son, and then going to Husband, it doesnt change anything` try the updated version

Answer (score 0):

You need to set date `yearRange` in your else statement, and change maxDate to use `new Date()`

```js
$('#relation1').on('change', function() {


  let relation1 = $("#relation1").val();
  let minusDate = 18;

  //User selected husband or wife from the dropdown
  if (relation1 == "Husband" || relation1 == "Wife") {
    minusDate = 75;
  }

  let today = new Date();
  today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - minusDate);
  
  $("#dob").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: today,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: today.getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear()
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Gender -->
    <div class="row">
        <label class="fm-input"> Relation :</label>
        <select class="fmRelation" id="relation1" required>
            <option value="Husband"> Husband </option>
            <option value="Wife"> Wife </option>
            <option value="Son"> Son </option>
            <option value="Daughter"> Daughter </option>
        </select>
    </div>
<!-- END -->

<!-- Date of Birth-->
    <div class="row">
        <label class="fm-inputph3"> Date Of Birth :</label>
        <input type="text" id="dob" class="fm-inputph3" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" required>
    </div>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- END dob -->
```

Comment: ..I used your code but it doesnt solve my problem,, I need to display years between 2001 and 2019 (if the user selected son or daughter )  and between 2001 and 1944 (if  the user selected husband or wife).. This means the children should be under 18 years while parents should be over 18 years and less than 75 years

Comment: @Martin but the son and daughter date range is fine? and in your question you said the husband and wife date picker is working fine.

Comment: - son and daughter range is fine,, but when I change to Husband or wife the years dont change...

Answer (score 0):

[datepicker2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuUmi.png)[datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4acZ0.png)This works fine as per your requirement.  it will show year range between 16th April 2001 and 16th April 2019 for son/daughter. Just add the else block and let me know
CHECK IMAGE IT WORKS AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT FOR SON/DAUGHTER.

```
else{
         var today = new Date();
         var mindate=new Date();
         mindate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear()-18);
         mindate.setMonth(today.getMonth());

            $( function() {
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    minDate:mindate,
                    maxDate:today 

                });
            });
            //End dob
        }
```

Comment: When you select 2011 then it will show upto 2019.because at a time it will show only 10 dropdown values.I am adding one more image for your clarification.

Comment: check now I have added one more image datepicker2 and let me know

Comment: Welcome Martin.